# Meaning of @12 in output from nm

Tags: gcc, linker

On Linux environment, compiling with gcc, I cannot link to a library because my function (let's call it `test()` ) doesn't get linked.
The "nm" output for this function is the following:

```
0x00000000 T _test@12
```

I think the `@12` is the reason of all my problems.

Does anyone know what the `@12` means and how it gets there? I would expect a "`_test`" and not "`_test@12`".

Comment: Do you have any arguments to the function? I might be off here, but I think the 12 might signify the number of bytes in your argument list, normally seen with a [__stdcall calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(v=vs.100).aspx). (Although the Linux issue confuses me here) The library is not compiled for Windows by any chance, is it?

Comment: You probably need to describe your environment a bit more carefully.  Which version of GCC?  Which variant of Linux?  You seem to be on a 32-bit system (you get a 16-digit offset on a 64-bit system).  What compiler options did you use?  How exactly is the function declared and defined?  I tried a 64-bit compilation and got `test` with no leading underscore or trailing `@NN` with GCC 4.1.2 on RHEL 5.x (ancient, but available and convenient).

Comment: It looks like a [symbol version](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html#VERSION).  Have you built the library? What is the input of `nm`, the library or your object file?

Comment: The @ refers to the library version required. If it won't link then presumably the library is too old. If that's not it then you have a mistake somewhere.